# PHP PDO Insert function with unknown number of variables

Tags: php, insert, pdo, explode

Trying to build a function that can insert into a SQL database regardless of how many or how few variables there are. Currently my function is not working.

```
function insert($table, $columns, $results){
    global $dbh;
    $results = explode(',',$results); 
    $val= ''; 
    $ex = '';
    foreach($results as $result){ 
        $val .= ":" . $result . ","; 
        $ex = "':" . $result . "' => $result,"; 
    }
    $val = rtrim($val, ','); 
    $ex = rtrim($ex, ',');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($val)";
    $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($ex));
}
```

Called like this:  `insert('users','email,pwd,forename,surname,level,status',$vals);`

Where as I managed to get it working for my Select function.

```
function check($table,$columns,$results){
    global $dbh;
    $columns = explode(',',$columns);
    $results = explode(',',$results); 
    $whr= ''; 
    $int = 0;
    foreach($columns as $column){ 
        $whr.= " AND " . $column . " = '{$results[$int]}'"; 
        $int += 1; 
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE status != 'D' $whr";
    $return = 0;
    foreach($dbh->query($sql) as $check){ 
        $return = 1; 
    } 
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Try echoing out `$sql` so we can see the exact text of the query you're preparing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would probably pass your columns and values into the function as an associative array.  This helps force the fact that the function caller must pass an equal number of both.  At the very least you should have logic that compares the number of the passed in columns and value elements to make sure they are equal.  You might try something like this (note I am also passing the DB connection in as a parameter, which is better coding practice).

```
function insert($db, $table, $key_value_array) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' '; 
    $columns = '(';
    $values = '(';
    foreach ($key_value_array as $k => $v) {
        $columns .= '`' . $k . '`, ';
        $values .= "'" . $v . "', ";
    }
    $columns = rtrim($columns, ', ') . ')';
    $values = rtrim($values, ', ') . ')';
    $sql .= $columns . ' VALUES ' . $values;
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
}
```

Comment: That created it but is missing the values

Comment: @RobinKnight Note that I stated my function requires a associative array of column/value pairs to be passed.

Comment: @RobinKnight I made an edit.  I didn't use proper concatenation operator in the loop.

Comment: Like this for the array:  insert('users', array('email' => $email, 'pwd' => $pwd, 'forename' => $forename, 'surname' => $surname, 'level' => 0, 'status' => 'A')); ??????

Comment: @RobinKnight Yes that array would work.  I think the problem you might have had was that I typoed the $columns and $values assignments in my original answer.  See my latest comment and edits.

Comment: I've got this working and it seams like a far better way to do things. How would the SELECT * version of this work using an associate array. It would make more sense to keep things consistent and do them all like this.

Comment: @RobinKnight Really it would not be much different other than for a select you wouldn't need an associative array (since you are not sending values), just an array of column names. So, for loop would only populate the columns values (which of course wouldn't be bracketed in parenthesis).  You could pass in an associative array to build your where clause assuming that you always know the logic to be used (i.e. always AND $column = $value). Optionally to make more flexible you might just pass in the where clause as a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method I use...

```
public function iInsert($table,$columns,$values)
    {

        # prepare the insert statement
        $col_str = "(" . implode(",",$columns) . ")";

        # is this a set of values or a select statement?
        if (is_array($values)){
            # this is an array of values
            foreach($values as $value){
                $cnv_val[] = $this->checkNULL($value);
            }
            $q = array_fill(0,count($columns),'?');
            $val_str = "VALUES (" . implode(",", $q)  . ")";

        }else{
            # assume this is a select statement for insert 
            $val_str = $values;
        }

        $syntax_str = "INSERT INTO $table $col_str \r\n$val_str";
        # execute the insert

        $sth = $this->iExec($syntax_str, $cnv_val, "inserted");

        # return the rows affected as a string
        return $sth;

    }
```

This example instantiates a class with the method but to help you get an idea...

```
*   INSERT - 
*       *** iInsert( string $table, array $columns, array [or string] $values ); ***
*       Returns: rows affected.
*
*       Example 1:
*
*       $result_array = $test_db->iInsert(  "BIDDING_BASIS_CODES", 
*                           array('BIDDING_BASIS_CODE', 'CODE_DESC',            'CODE_ACTIVE_FLAG', 'IBR_CODE', 'LAST_MOD_BY_USER_ID',  'LAST_MOD_DATE_TIME'),
*                           array('TEST',               'TEST CODE - DISREGARD','N',                'N',        'cd_boust',             '1/1/2011 09:00')       
*                           );
*       echo $result;
*
*       Example 2:
*
*       $result_array = $test_db->iInsert(  "BIDDING_BASIS_CODES", 
*                           array('BIDDING_BASIS_CODE', 'CODE_DESC',            'CODE_ACTIVE_FLAG', 'IBR_CODE', 'LAST_MOD_BY_USER_ID',  'LAST_MOD_DATE_TIME'),
*                           "SELECT 
*                               Row_1,
*                               Row_2,
*                               Row_3,
*                               Row_4,
*                               Row_5,
*                               Row_6
*                           FROM
*                               tablename"      
*                           );
*       echo $result;
```